# Python - Generate a multiple row update query

Tags: python, sql, sql-update

My goal is dynamically generate in Python a SQL query similar to,

```
UPDATE SURV_SCF_ID_STATUS
    SET AGE_STATUS = CASE NAME
        WHEN 'entityXp1' THEN '1'
        WHEN 'entityXp3' THEN '0'
        WHEN 'entityXpto1' THEN '1'
        WHEN 'entityXpto3' THEN '1'
    END
WHERE NAME IN ('entityXp1', 'entityXp3', 'entityXpto1', 'entityXpto3')
```

This is what I have so far, 
but still feels like an ugly hack,

```
logs_age_list = [['entityXp1', '1'], ['entityXp3', '0'], ['entityXp1', '1'], ['entityXpto3', '1']]
conditions_list = []
where_list = []
for entity, status in logs_age_list:
conditions_list.append("\t\tWHEN %(entity)s THEN %(value)s" % locals() )
where_list.append(entity)

conditions_string = '\n'.join(conditions_list)
where_string = ', '.join(where_list)

sql = '''
UPDATE SURV_SCF_ID_STATUS
     SET AGE_STATUS = CASE NAME
%(conditions_string)s
END
WHERE NAME IN (%(where_string)s)
''' % locals()

print sql
```

Is there some more obvious way to do it?
I didn't find any Python module which allow this.

Thanks

Comment: Second line of the Zen of Python says "Explicit is better than implicit". I would avoid '' % locals() at any cost.

Comment: Doesn't it also says,
"Beautiful is better than ugly / Simple is better than complex"?

I started using it for readability purposes after reading wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips and as the Zen states, "Readability counts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the condition_string via

```
conditions_string = ' '.join(["\t\tWHEN %s THEN %s\n" % (x, y) for x, y in logs_age_list])
```

and the where_string as

```
where_string = ', '.join([duo[0] for duo inlogs_age_list])
```

then do something like

```
sql = '''
UPDATE SURV_SCF_ID_STATUS
SET AGE_STATUS = CASE NAME
%s
END
WHERE NAME IN (%s)
''' % (conditions_string, where_string)
```

But in generall you should try to use the execute methods of the DB modules to avoid SQL injection.

Here is an example taken from http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'IBM'
c.execute("... where symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = (symbol,)
c.execute('select * from stocks where symbol=?', t)
```

Comment: My module generates the data so it shoud be sanitized 
but how could I have a multiple update with those SLQ injection precautions?
Thanks for the optimizations.